# How to group by similar rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I applied groupby on a dataframe

> df.groupby('Category').sum()

after which the result dataframe looks like this

```
               height      weight 
General  42.849980  157.500553    
GENERAL  49.607315  177.340407 
Genera  56.293531  171.524640  
CategoryA  48.421077  144.251986  
CategoryB  48.421077  144.251986
CategoryC  48.421077  144.251986
```

I need to group General, GENERAL and Genera in a single row and the result to look like

```
General    123.849980  300.500553    
CategoryA  48.421077  144.251986  
CategoryB  48.421077  144.251986
CategoryC  48.421077  144.251986
```

How can I accomplish this ?

Edit: Got the solution with the regex. 
Is there any way if I need to categorize General, GENERAL, Genera and CategoryA into a single group ?

Comment: Your expected output doesn't show what you're describing

Comment: @ninesalt The sum values may be different. But the aim is to categorize General, GENERAL and Genera and get the corresponding sum.

Comment: If using some build-in function for string match , the CategoryA   and CategoryB may consider as one , that is the problem, so you may need to build your own natural language process

Comment: Maybe try `df['Category'] = np.where(df['Category').str.lower().str.startswith('genera'), 'General', df['Category']` Then do your groupby again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the category you are grouping by is in the index, you can do:

```
import re

result = (
    df
    .groupby(df.index.str.replace("genera.*", "General", flags=re.IGNORECASE))
    .sum()
)
```

**Edit:** If you don't want to use regex, you can use a different approach with `.map`. In the example below I assume that your categories are in a column named `Category`:

```
mapping = {
    "General": "CategoryA",
    "GENERAL": "CategoryA",
    "Genera": "CategoryA",
}
result = (
    df
    .groupby(df.Category.map(mapping).fillna(df.Category))
    .sum()
)
```

Comment: Very clean solution!

Comment: Thanks. But is there any way other than regex to implement this.
If I need to group General, GENERAL, Genera and CategroyA in to a single group how can I do ?

Comment: @Prajwal I added an alternative solution which does not require regex.